# Question on DC analysis of BJT - Common Base

Tags: bjt, analysis

I'm trying to solve a question from my book. The answer for the question is given but I keep getting a different answer. I don't know if I'm doing it the wrong way or the book is wrong.

This is the question: [image]
This is my working: [image]

The answer is apparently 0.921mA but I get a different answer.

The question also asks for voltage gain and current gain. I did not attempt those parts yet since I got stuck on the first part.

Comment: You seem to have mis-read the emitter resistor RE value.

Comment: @BrianDrummond You are correct. I did not notice that it is PNP and NPN so I assumeed the wrong side to be the emitter. As usual something small eludes me for so long.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$ I_E= \frac{(V_{EE}-V_{EB})}{R_E}=0,93 \text{mA} $$

$$ I_E=I_B+I_C=\frac{I_C}{\beta}+I_C$$

Therefore,
$$ I_C=I_E \times \frac{\beta}{(1+\beta)}=0.921 \text{mA} $$

Comment: This would be a better answer with some explanation.